# Can't receive reply using PySerial but hyperterminal works

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a device (Pololu Wixel) that I'm trying to communicate with using a serial connection over USB. Hyperterminal works fine but I'm trying to use Python for more flexibility. I can send commands to the device, but when I try to receive all I get is the command I just sent. However, if I open Hyperterminal, I'll receive the reply there to the command sent from the script. My code is below. I'm at a bit of a loss and it seems like this should be fairly straightforward. I appreciate any help.

```
import serial
import time

'''
Go through 256 COM ports and try to open them.
'ser' will be the highest port number. Fix this later.
'''

for i in range(256):

    currentPort = "COM" + str(i+1)

    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(currentPort,baudrate=115200,timeout=5)
        print("Success!!")
        print(ser.name)
    except:
        pass

print(ser.isOpen())
str = "batt"    #Command to request battery levels.
ser.write(str.encode())

x = ser.inWaiting()
print(x)

while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out = ser.readline()
    print(out.decode())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a break after finding an active port,
2. Try passing a different *eol* value to readline(), "\r" or "\r\n".

Comment: I got it to work with a combination of these two. Thank you very much!